# Prime number finder - optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a prime number finder that would work as fast as possible. This is the def function that is included in the program. I'm having problems with just one detail, which I have put in {brackets} below. I have also explained the main parameters.

```
import math
def is_prime(x):
    c=0      #a simple counter
    a=7      #a (+ k*6)a group of all possible deviders of the number(if 2,3 and 5 are taken away)
    b=11      #the other group
    {r=x**(1/2)}      #root of the number
    {f=math.floor(r)}       #floor of the root
    if x%2!=0 and x%3!=0 and x%5!=0:      #eliminate all multiples of 2,3 and 5
        while (c==0 and {a<f}):         #while loop
                if x%a==0 or x%b==0:
                        c+=1          #if true -> will break
                a+=6        #adding 6 to a and b (numbers that have a potential to devide
                b+=6
        if c==0:       #if a number not divisable by anything, return number
            return x
```

This function doesn't work properly. If instead of floored squared root of my number I just replace it with x/3 it will work just fine. But the problem is that I don't want to check all the possible dividers in between x**(1/2) and x/3, because it will only slow the function, nothing else. So here is the code that works:

```
import math
def is_prime(x):
c=0
a=7
b=11
if x%2!=0 and x%3!=0 and x%5!=0:
        while (c==0 and a<x/3):
                if x%a==0 or x%b==0:
                        c+=1
                a+=6
                b+=6
        if c==0:
            return x
```

If anyone sees the problem, help please :D

Comment: 1/2 is 0.  Use 0.5 or 1.0/2.0 instead.

Comment: @pjs: Compatibility issue: in Python 3 1/2 actually does yield 0.5 (float division), while `1//2` yields 0 (int division). In Python2, `//` also exists and should be used for integer division to simplify ports to P3.

Comment: @Olaf the tag says python-2.7

Comment: @pjs: That's why I wrote "Compatibility issue". Keeping the limited maintenance period for P2 in mid, It might be good to give hints for changed semantics. Also it might be very well possible the TO got this code from P3 and was not aware. I think a correction should always include a short explanation. The answer of DTing for instance does include a hint enough to make one think about P3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above, python2 performs integer division so `1/2 == 0`

- You can write your root as:

  ```
  x**0.5
  ```
- or using math.sqrt:

  ```
  math.sqrt(x)
  ```

The naive primality test can be implemented like this:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n<=1: return False
    if n<=3: return True
    if not n%2 or not n%3: return False
    i=5
    while i*i<=n:
        if n%i==0: return False
        i+=2
        if n%i==0: return False
        i+=4
    return True
```